# Re-deploy of a Tomcat application causes the active sessions to be dropped

Tags: session, tomcat, deployment, tomcat8

I have a tomcat application which I deploy by placing the new `my-project.war` file into the `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/` directory on my server (via `scp`).

Every time I do this, the new copy is live a few seconds later. The only problem is that it drops all the sessions.

All the documentation I can find tells me that Tomcat should restore the sessions by default. This does seem to be the case when I restart the Tomcat service, but not when I redeploy...

Can anyone tell me whats going on here? I don't fully understand why it works to deploy this way in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default session manager - `StandardManager` saves the sessions in `<tomcat-home>/work/<app-name>/SESSIONS.ser`. When you stop tomcat, the sessions are serialized into that file. When you start it - they are loaded from it.

But when you re-deploy your applications two things happen:

1. Tomcat `un-deploys` the old app and *deletes* the `<tomcat-home>/work/<app-name>/` folder, thus removes the saved sessions
2. Tomcat deploys the new app and creates a new folder

Or in two words - tomcat deletes the saved sessions on un-deploy. I guess this is because:

- the re-deploy is implemented as undeploy -> deploy. I.e. the 'undeploy' step does not know if a new version of the app will be deployed, so it makes sure to properly clean up after itself.
- it's better from security perspective

Comment: I see. Thanks, thats very helpful. So would you expect this to be fixed by setting the path the sessions are stored to? It would depend on whether the sessions are stored in disk at runtime, or only stored for a restart. The other option I can think of would be to implement my own Manager (or use a non standard one).